Почему так много слов заканчивалось на букву еръ до реформы 1918 года?
Связано ли это с законом открытого слога?

Связано, конечно: эти слова в современном языке заканчиваются на твердый согласный. В Сети много материалов по этой теме.

Букву Ъ отменили в 1918 году, назвав ее буквой-транжиром.  Раньше она обозначала редуцированный (очень краткий гласный, похожий на О), но ведь редуцированные пали еще в XIII веке.

Это же уму непостижимо, сколько на нее тратилось денег! Правда, в конце существительных Ъ указывал на принадлежность их к мужскому роду, да и оглушения согласных не было (если по образцу церковнославянского языка). Но это же мелочи)
Источник: https://kulturologia.ru/blogs/100318/38128/
 То, что эта буква употребляется при написании слишком 
 часто, было замечено задолго до нововведений. На то, чтобы 
 напечатать ее на бумаге тратилось восемь процентов времени, 
 в денежном выражении она обходилась российской казне в 
 четыреста тысяч рублей в год, то есть была самой 
 дорогостоящей и при этом не читалась.


Основным законом древнерусского языка был закон открытого
слога (ЗОС). Сущность закона открытого слога в том, что слог
мог оканчиваться только на слоговой звук (гласный или
плавный согласный r, l). В древнерусских словах все слоги
были открытыми: столъ, братъ, събирати.

Из статьи Закон открытого слога:
...Давайте возьмем для примера любое слово и посмотрим. Ну вот хотя бы — город. Как мы его разобьем на слоги? Го-род. Один открытый, один закрытый. Никаких проблем. В древнерусском языке такого быть не могло. Там существовал железный закон — все слоги должны были оканчиваться на гласный. Этот закон напрямую вытекал из так называемого принципа восходящей звучности — отличительной особенности праславянского языка, предка всех славянских языков.
ДОПОЛНИТЕЛЬНЫЙ МАТЕРИАЛ
P. S.  Об экономии в языке
Вообще говоря, я считаю, что русский язык развивается по правильному пути целесообразного и оптимального использования языковых средств. И это касается не только фонетики и графики.
Получив в наследство греческую грамматику, мы значительно упростили систему обозначения времен, которая кажется такой неуклюжей в английском языке (мое мнение). В то же время у нас развитая система словоизменения, которая позволяет использовать свободный порядок слов.
Что нам до этого порядка? На этом построена мелодика русской речи,  когда тоническим ударением мы выделяем нужное слово в нужной позиции, свободно переставляя слова. Ну, кажется, что свободно, а на самом деле это интуитивный выбор носителей языка. Где еще это можно увидеть?
И неожиданный вывод по теме)) Если существует величие русской души, то оно проявлено в языке, уж это бесспорно) А дальше уже по Тургеневу.

Я не понял: что не могло быть в древнерусском языке?

Я добавила текст в цитату из статьи

Я всё равно не понимаю: почему так часто встречался еръ на конце слова? Как закон открытого слога привёл к этому?

Слово в современном языке может заканчиваться на гласную, твердую согласную и мягкую согласную. Но в древнерусском языке мола быть только гласная (закон открытого слога), поэтому после тв. и мягк. согласных писались буквы ерь и еръ. Я могу предположить, что вариант на тв. согласный самый частотный.  Или у вас другая статистика?

Кстати, вы ничего не ответили и никак не отметили мой ответ на другом сайте https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/27364/what-exactly-is-going-on-for-the-handful-of-verbs-which-have-an-imperative-мте/27385#27385  Вероятно, тоже не поняли. Тогда я с вашего позволения задам его на  этом сайте.  Прошу ответить на мои комментарии, так как материл идет незамеченным, а он полезен для общества с моей точки зрения. Это касается и этого вопроса.
